# Do I need homepage logo to redirect to the homepage again?

Tags: html, seo

I've noticed that most website has a logo in its homepage. 
The logo then redirect to itself, which is the same page. 
I wonder if this has a positive impact for SEO ? 
I mean, why I need to add a logo to redirect to itself ? 

My question is for the homepage itself only, if for other pages has logo and redirect to homepage, then I understand the useful of it .

Any logic explanation for this ?

Comment: You may get better answers on http://ux.stackexchange.com. This site is not meant to answer questions like yours. Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard UI principal that most users will be used to. Sometimes it is useful to refresh the homepage, even if you are already there.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't think that this would give a notable positive impact for ranking in search engines.

I'm a web developer and i'm also used to do what you described for the following reason:
its like a quasi standard...

The user expects that she/he will be redirected to the homepage.
But if she/he don't has the experience from the homepage (considiring that the homepage was the landing page) she/he maybe wouldn't expect the logo to be a hyperlink also on the following sites.

A website is a user interface and the user have to learn how to use it therefor sometimes consistency goes before other parameters like logic or necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Logos are a critical aspect of marketing. Company's logos are intended to be face of a company which allows customers to identify with the company's core brand which is also the cause that people use it on homepage to redirect. It is just good way to refresh your website. In SEO there is not big impact of logo redirect .